# How to count users answers in Console

Tags: c#, counter

First days with C# and already stuck. My question is how to count all the answers that a user gave trying to find out what the random number is? And then put-it in the las sentence withe the right answer. That's how the "quiz" looks like:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("The secret number\n");

        Random randomerare = new Random();
        int slump_tal = randomerare.Next(1, 101);

        Console.WriteLine("Write your number and we'll see where it lands:\n");
            string user_nr = Console.ReadLine();
            int tal = Convert.ToInt32(user_nr);
            Console.WriteLine();

            while (tal > slump_tal)
        {
                Console.WriteLine("Wrong! Your number is too big!\n");
                user_nr = Console.ReadLine();
                tal = Convert.ToInt32(user_nr);
        }
            while (tal < slump_tal)

        {
            Console.WriteLine("Wrong Your number is too low!\n");
                user_nr = Console.ReadLine();
                tal = Convert.ToInt32(user_nr);
        }

            while (tal == slump_tal)
            {
        Console.WriteLine("Bravo! That's the correct number\n");
            break;
            }

        Console.WriteLine("The secret number was: {0}\n\nPush the button to finish", slump_tal);

        Console.ReadKey(true);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

There are 2 steps in your code. And you mixed them up.

Step 1: do a while loop to keep getting input from user.

Step 2: inside each loop, you need to validate the input against the number.

It should be 1 big while() loop with 3 if (). Let me know if you need example code.

Answer (score 0):

I would do it like this:

```
 1. Get a number
 2. While the user is not hitting the right number:
      2.1 let the user know if the number was too big or too small
      2.2 ask for another number
      2.3 count number-of-attems + 1
 3. If the user arrived here, it means it has the number right, print number-of-attems
```

In code, this could look like this:

```
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("The secret number\n");

        Random randomerare = new Random();
        int slump_tal = randomerare.Next(1, 101);

        Console.WriteLine("Write your number and we'll see where it lands:\n");
        Console.WriteLine();


        int user_nr = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

        // Here you can store the attempts
        int attempts = 1;

        // While the user provides the wrong answer, we iterate
        while(slump_tal != user_nr)
        {

            // We add 1 to the counter
            attempts++;

            if (slump_tal > slump_tal)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Wrong Your number is too low!\n");
            }
            else 
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Wrong! Your number is too big!\n");
            }

            user_nr = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        }

        Console.WriteLine($"Bravo! That's the correct number. you did it in {attempts} attemps");
        Console.WriteLine("The secret number was: {0}\n\nPush the button to finish", slump_tal);
        Console.ReadKey(true);
    }
```

Comment: Hi @Lez, if this helped you to understand how to do it, please mark it as the answer so others can benefit from it... if this was not enough please let us know so we can tailor a better answer for you... Welcome to StackOverflow!!  :)

Comment: and to whoever marked -1, please leave a comment on why, so I can provide better answers next time. Thanks!

Comment: @CarlosGarcia Not my down vote, but my guess: because your answer lacks any explanation. You just postet a 'fixed' version. Alex answer above explains issues and let the (as stated: 'still learning') OP, figure out what went wrong. Don't get me wrong: thanks for beeing a helping hand on this board!

Comment: Tahnks @nilsK, I don't care the downvote, my stocks already went down enough :D I care about understanding the why. I tried to write self explanatory code with comments instead,. but you are right that a some context would have helped, specially to beginners. I upvoted the previous answer as well :). Thanks for your comment!